# Determine the $n$th string among those of a given length in alphabetical order starting at a given string and using a given character set?

Tags: functions, number-systems, combinatorics-on-words

When building strings using a particular character set (the set can change), such as in a brute-force password cracking, how would I determine which string occurs in the $n$th position when the strings are ordered alphabetically for each length, starting at a given string? (Conversely, what is the position of a given string among those of the same  length, starting at a given string of that length?)

For example, if the character set is $ABCDEFG$, then among the strings of length 2, starting at $AA$, string $AC$ is in position 3 and string $AE$ is in position 5:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{position:}&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
\text{string:}&AA&AB&AC&AD&AE&AF&AG 
\end{matrix}
$$

I am programming in Delphi and want to use a function that returns the string:
function CharArrayPosToStr(ca: TCharArray; len, pos: Integer): String;

The purpose is to break the job into working sets of given lengths, so I need to be able to quickly determine something like:  Set 1 starts at $AAAA$ and ends at $AAQA$ and set 2 begins at $AAQB$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [shortlex ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order) list of all words on the seven-letter alphabet $ABCDEFG$ is 
$$A,B, C, D, E, F, G, AA, AB, ..., GF, GG, AAA, ..., GGG, ...$$

If we replace the letters $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$ with the nonzero digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$, then
this becomes the list of positive integers written in [bijective base-7 notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) (*in numerical order*):
$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, ..., 76, 77, 111, ..., 777, ...$$

More generally, in the shortlex ordering of all the words on the digit-set $\{1, 2, ..., k\} (k \ge 1)$, the $m$th word is $a_n a_{n−1} ... a_1 a_0$, where

$$\begin{align}
a_0 & =  m   - q_0 k ,   & & q_0  =  f\left(\frac m   k \right)  \\
a_1 & =  q_0 - q_1 k ,   & & q_1  =  f\left(\frac {q_0} k \right) \\
a_2 & =  q_1 - q_2 k ,   & & q_2  =  f\left(\frac {q_1} k \right) \\
    & \vdots             & &     \vdots  \\
a_n & =  q_{n-1} - 0 k , & & q_n  =  f\left(\frac {q_{n-1}} k \right)  = 0
\end{align}
$$

and 
$$f(x) = \lceil x \rceil - 1.$$

So, to find the $m$th word in the shortlex ordering of words on an alphabet of $k$ letters, just use the preceding algorithm to find the bijective base-$k$ numeral for $m$ (and convert back to letters using the reverse substitution).

Also, note that the list-position $m$ of a given word is obtained simply by making the digit-substitution and then reading the result (say $a_n a_{n−1} ... a_1 a_0$) as a bijective base-$k$ numeral: 
$$
m = (a_n a_{n−1} ... a_1 a_0)_{\text{bijective base-}k} = a_n\ k^n + a_{n-1}\ k^{n-1} +  ... + a_1\ k^1 + a_0\ k^0.$$

**NB**:
If you're interested in the positions of certain words *relative* to that of others (i.e. in a particular list segment), just find the relative position by the appropriate subtractions.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but the problem seemed familiar, and I recognized I've had a solution for years. In VBA, you can do it like this:

```
Function ShortlexPos(sInp As String, sSym As String) As Long
  If Len(sInp) Then ShortlexPos = InStr(sSym, Right(sInp, 1)) _
     + Len(sSym) * ShortlexPos(Left(sInp, Len(sInp) - 1), sSym)
End Function
```

For example, columns in Excel are named

A, B, ..., Y, Z, AA, AB, ..., AX, AY, AZ, BA, ... XFD

The position of the last column is given by

```
ShortlexPos("XFD", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

... which (correctly) returns 16384.

The complementary function returns the sequence at a given position:

```
Function ShortLexStr(iNum As Long, sSym As String) As String
  If iNum > 0 Then ShortlexStr = ShortlexStr((iNum - 1) \ Len(sSym), sSym) & _
   Mid(sSym, ((iNum - 1) Mod Len(sSym)) + 1, 1)
End Function
```

For example,

```
ShortLexStr(16384, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

returns XFD